# Identify unique records on CSV based on specific columns

Tags: text-processing, csv, uniq, deduplication

If the input is

```
foo,bar,baz
bar,baz,qux
qux,quux,baz
bar,foo,qux
waldo,fred,garply
```

the output should be

```
foo,bar,baz
bar,baz,qux
waldo,fred,garply
```

As you can see, records are deduplicated based on the 3rd column's value. If multiple records have the same 3rd column value, pick a random one (or the first one; doesn't matter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiomatic awk answer is `awk -F, '!seen[$3]++' file`

That will print a line the first time a value is seen in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not bothered about the order of the output, can just use `sort`, as below.

- `-t,` sets the field delimiter to ","
- `-k3` defines the sort key as the third field
- `-u` indicates that only unique results are wanted

  ```
  $ sort -t, -k3 -u file
  foo,bar,baz
  waldo,fred,garply
  bar,baz,qux
  $
  ```