# Deduplicate CSV rows based on a specific column, with a CSV parser

Tags: linux, csv, csvkit, miller

I searched for this task, and found the following older questions:

- [Removing Duplicates from a CSV based on specified columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681059/removing-duplicates-from-a-csv-based-on-specified-columns)
- [Identify unique records on CSV based on specific columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444476/identify-unique-records-on-csv-based-on-specific-columns)

But I can't use `awk` because my data is a complex CSV file with multiple nested double quotes.

Let's say I want to deduplicate the following (simplified case):

```
Ref,xxx,zzz
ref1,"foo, bar, base",qux
ref1,"foo, bar, base",bar
ref2,aaa,bbb
```

In the output I need it as follows:

```
Ref,xxx,zzz
ref1,"foo, bar, base",qux
ref2,aaa,bbb
```

No `awk` solution, please, only with any CSV parser.

I tried the following:

```
mlr --csv uniq -a -g Ref file.csv
```

But it's an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run

```
mlr --csv head -n 1 -g Ref input.csv
```

to get the first row grouped by `Ref`

Answer (score 5):

Miller's `uniq` sub-command returns unique records with the fields with which the uniqueness was determined.  Any other fields are discarded.  You are getting an error because the sub-command's `-a` (use all fields) and `-g` (use specific fields) options are incompatible.

A good solution using only Miller [was already given](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747425/116858). Using the `head` sub-command with `-n 1` while grouping on the `Ref` field is probably the most convenient solution.

You may also make Miller use the same kind of operation that is commonly used in `awk` (`!seen[$1]++`), but since Miller does not have a post-increment operator, it will be slightly longer:

```bash
mlr --csv filter '@seen[$Ref] += 1; @seen[$Ref] == 1' file.csv
```

You could also use Miller for converting the data into JSON, then use `jq` to perform a `unique_by()` operation, and then get Miller to convert the data back into CSV:

```bash
mlr --c2j cat file.csv | jq 'unique_by(.Ref)' | mlr --j2c cat
```